# Is there legislation in Australia (or individual states) that outline the penalties for juror misconduct?

Tags: australia, jury, legislature

While there have been penalties in the past for jurors posting case info to Facebook, researching case, etc, is there a specific Act/piece of legislation that outlines the consequences for doing so? In particular to the state of WA, but any other state info would be appreciated :)

So is it simply the personal integrity of the juror to abide by standards of integrity, or are they controlled by law (Australia-wide/Australian state context)?

I'm looking for any precise law outlining the above^

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

There is one for each jurisdiction. They are called the [Jury Act](http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ja197791/index.html#s67) ([new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) link) or some variation thereof (e.g. [Juries Act](http://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/consol_act/ja200097/) [victoria](/questions/tagged/victoria)). In some states, jury misconduct is an offence, in others it is not.

Part 9 deals with offences. Those that can be committed by jurors are s68B Disclosure of information by jurors etc and s68C Inquiries by juror about trial matters prohibited. Both are punishable by fines of up to 50 penalty units (in 2020 a penalty unit is AUD 110, so up to AUD 55,000).

In addition, under s72A requires a juror to swear or affirm "I swear by Almighty God that I will give a true verdict according to the evidence" - knowingly making a false oath or affirmation is punishable under the Oaths Act.

While not necessarily an offence, the act defines "irregularity" in s75C.